# How do i import the V1JobBuilderClass from the java kubernetes client version 18?

Tags: java, kubernetes, gradle

The client on master and the 18.0.0 release branch still has the class, but after upgrading from version 11 to version 18 intellij idea says that this class doesn't exist and the code doesn't compile. It does exist here https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/fluent/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/openapi/models/V1JobBuilder.java , so how do i import it?

I am using gradle.

```
implementation 'io.kubernetes:client-java:18.0.0'

import io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1JobBuilder;
```

Tried switching to generating the V1Job from yaml as well as using the setters (new V1Job().spec(...)), but its a very tedious process to translate it, and it would be safer to just not touch the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's still there:

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/fluent/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/openapi/models/V1JobBuilder.java#L5

But its re-packaged in a separate dependency:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.kubernetes/client-java-api-fluent

I believe if you add that dependency to your project it should work correctly, if it doesn't please let us know.

credits: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/issues/2706#issuecomment-1593625113